# Pass Windows log in information in a HTTP header

Tags: java, windows, rest, active-directory

I have a Java swing application that communicate with a API through HTTP REST. for now I use authentication window to pass username (`BASE64 encoding`) and password (`MD5 Hash`) inside a HTTP header. Now I want to use windows credentials to log into the application. Is there a way that I can get log in info and pass it to the server.?

**Update :** I have got the username by using `System.getenv("username")` but I saw many posts saying getting password is impossible. Is it true or is there any method to get currently logged user's password.?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need SPNEGO with Kerberos.